# How can I put the value (PENDING) on my column (order_status) using array php

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have two tables `tb_empgrocery` and `tb_empgroc_master`. When I click order now, the items that I've ordered will be saved into the two tables. `tb_empgrocery` saves all the items each row and `tb_empgroc_master` reads the each row from the first table and counts items and summarize it.

```
case "Add":
    $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $unitprc = $_POST['unitprc'];
    $amt = $_POST['amt'];
    $coopmemid = $_SESSION['kiosk']['is_coopmemID_kiosk'];
    $totamt = 0;
    $totitm = count($itemno);
    $a_empgroid = array();
    for($x=0; $x<$totitm; $x++) {
        $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount) 
                     VALUES ('$coopmemid',(NOW()),'$itemno[$x]','$qty[$x]','$unitprc[$x]','$amt[$x]')";
        $atecCoop->query($Addquery);
        $totamt+=$amt[$x];
        $inserted_id = $atecCoop->insert_id;
        array_push($a_empgroid,$inserted_id);
    }
    $Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (date_ordered, total_items, total_amount) VALUES ((NOW()), '$totitm', '$totamt')";
    $atecCoop->query($Savequery);
    $empgrocmstid = $atecCoop->insert_id;
    $orderno = date('y-m-').str_pad($empgrocmstid, 10, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $sql = "UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET order_no='$orderno' WHERE empgrocmstID='$empgrocmstid'";
    $atecCoop->query($sql);
    foreach($a_empgroid as $empgrocid) {
        $sql = "UPDATE tb_empgrocery SET order_no='$orderno' WHERE empgrocID='$empgrocid'";
        $atecCoop->query($sql);
    }
break;
```

I want to add the value "Pending" in my 2nd table with the row to the column of `order_status` by adding it in here.

```
$Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (//here-order_status, date_ordered, total_items, total_amount) VALUES (//and here, (NOW()), '$totitm', '$totamt')";
```

Another array will be inserted i think but I don't know how to

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am quite confuse with your problem. But if want to add data for order_status field, why don't you automatically insert it same with the other field.
$Savequery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (order_status, date_ordered, total_items, total_amount) VALUES ('Pending', (NOW()), '$totitm', '$totamt')"; but if I miss something, please explain your question further.

Comment: Yup you're right. Thanks @Hope